# UserControl DataBinding properties not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, user-controls

I have a UserControl that has some properties that I wish to bind to XAML.

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" DataContext="{RelativeSource Self}">
<UserControl.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding BackgroundImage}" Stretch="UniformToFill" AlignmentX="Center" AlignmentY="Bottom"/>
</UserControl.Background>

<Grid Name="mainGrid">
    <Label Canvas.ZIndex="-1" Foreground="Gray" Content="{Binding VersionNumber}" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="versionLabel" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And code-behind:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string VersionNumber { private get; set; }
    public ImageSource BackgroundImage { private get; set; }

    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

}
```

I have a window that contains the UserControl, like so

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SomeNameSpace"

        Title="MainWindow" 
        MinHeight="400" MinWidth="400" >
<local:UserControl1 BackgroundImage="images\background.png" VersionNumber="10"/>
```

Of course, the actual window does not show anything, the background is blank and the `Label.Content` is null, but the Autos window shows me that the properties have been set correctly, like this.
[image: Autos]

I've been messing with this for the past 2 hours or so, I don't know whats going wrong.

**EDIT**
I've tried this

```
 private string versionNumber;
 public string VersionNumber { get { return this.versionNumber; } 
 set { 
      this.versionNumber = value; 
      OnPropertyChanged("VersionNumber"); 
  } 
}
```

And it still doesn't work, the label in this case does not update.

[image: result]

Comment: You are missing OnPropertyChange("yourpropertyname") in your properties set.

Comment: try to modify setter of your properties to public, and see if that fix the problem

Comment: @har07 the setter is public, its just the getter that's private.

@MihaiHantea See update, it still doesn't work even with a call to `OnPropertyChanged()`

Comment: @ron975 sorry, I meant try to modify the getter to `public`. Binding doesn't work with private property, so it may also has problem with private getter.

Comment: Alright, I just tried with a public getter, it yields the same result.

Comment: Binding RelativeSource=
    {RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type YourNamespace:YourParentControl}}, 
    Path=VersionNumber}

Comment: @MihaiHantea Could you clarify on `YourParentControl`? My UserControl is used by 2 different classes that both inherit from `System.Windows.Window`. 

`Content="{Binding RelativeSource= {RelativeSource Self}, Path=VersionNumber}"` doesn't work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this for label binding:

```
Content={Binding RelativeSource= {RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type wpfApplication1:UserControl1}}, Path=VersionNumber}
```

UserControl1 is the name of your user control class. You have to specify the namespace and the user control.

You can keep your private get it still works with this binding.

**EDIT**
Following your code I made this demo:

//window.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:wpfApplication1="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <wpfApplication1:UserControl1 VersionNumber="10"/>
</Grid>
```

//UserControl1

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:wpfApplication1="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" DataContext="{RelativeSource Self}">
<UserControl.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding BackgroundImage}" Stretch="UniformToFill" AlignmentX="Center" AlignmentY="Bottom"/>
</UserControl.Background>

<Grid Name="mainGrid">
    <Label Canvas.ZIndex="-1" Foreground="Gray" Content="{Binding RelativeSource= {RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type wpfApplication1:UserControl1}}, Path=VersionNumber}" 
           Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="versionLabel" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
</Grid>
```

UserControl1.cs

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _versionNumber;
    private ImageSource _backgroundImage;

    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string VersionNumber
    {
        private get { return _versionNumber; }
        set
        {
            _versionNumber = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("VersionNumber");
        }
    }

    public ImageSource BackgroundImage
    {
        get { return _backgroundImage; }
        set
        {
            _backgroundImage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("BackgroundImage");
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

As @anees suggested you can also use dependency properties for VersionNumber and BackgroundImage:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty VersionNumberProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "VersionNumber", typeof (string), typeof (UserControl1), new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));

    public string VersionNumber
    {
        get { return (string) GetValue(VersionNumberProperty); }
        set { SetValue(VersionNumberProperty, value); }
    }

public static readonly DependencyProperty BackgroundImageProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "BackgroundImage", typeof (ImageSource), typeof (UserControl1), new PropertyMetadata(default(ImageSource)));

    public ImageSource BackgroundImage
    {
        get { return (ImageSource) GetValue(BackgroundImageProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BackgroundImageProperty, value); }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel you haven't properly include the Usercontrol in MainWindow,
Include the following namespace in your MainWindow

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourNameSpace"
```

And add your Usercontrol like as follows:

```
<local:UserControl1 x:Name="somename" .... />
```

Comment: It seems I forgot to put that in somehow, I've updated the question to reflect adding the xmlns. Databinding still doesn't work however.

Comment: Have you tried to set dependency properties? http://wpftutorial.net/DependencyProperties.html

Answer (score 0):

May be datacontext issues because if that show's null then the context is not set properly